# How do I evaluate $e^{9\ln(x)(\frac{9}{x})}$

Tags: exponential-function

I am trying an FTC problem.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{9\ln x}e^t \,dt=\ ?$$

How do I evaluate $$e^{9\ln(x)(9/x)}$$

EDIT:  Ok, I made a mistake above, and put the chain rule result in the exponent!
Wrong!  Here is the correct way, using FTC:

$$\huge{\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{9\ln x}e^t \,dt=(e^{9lnx})\frac{9}{x}=(e^{lnx})^9(\frac{9}{x})=\frac{x^9}{1}\frac{9}{x}=9x^8}$$

Comment: Try to avoid using `\displaystyle` in the title of the question, since it appears too big on the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you did, but anyway: $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{9\ln x}e^t \,dt=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{9\ln x}-1)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^9-1)=9x^8.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \huge{e^{9\ln(x)(\frac{9}{x})}=e^{\ln(x)\frac{81}{x}}=(e^{\ln(x)})^{\frac{81}{x}}=x^{\frac{81}{x}}}$$

Comment: So, you claim that $x^{\frac{81}{x}}=x^2-9$?

Comment: Thanks, rewriting power to a power was helpful in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can switch the order of the factors. $\exp(abc)=\exp(bac)$.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I made a mistake above, and put the chain rule result in the exponent!
Wrong!  Here is the correct way, using FTC:

$$\huge{\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{9\ln x}e^t \,dt=(e^{9lnx})\frac{9}{x}=(e^{lnx})^9(\frac{9}{x})=\frac{x^9}{1}\frac{9}{x}=9x^8}$$